# Error: data and salt arguments required (User input object from angular not being received by node?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm new to the MEAN stack, trying basic apps with tutorials. 
Getting user input from a registration form using Angular. Password getting encrypted using bcrypt. When I log the user object that is being sent from the registration form, in the front-end the object has all the appropriate data. Posting using $http.post() method. Once the object is received in the back-end controller, all the fields say 'undefined'.

I saw that a couple of people have previously discussed this same error and the only conclusion that everyone arrived at, was that the bcrypt.hashSync() function wasn't receiving the password or receiving it as undefined. How do I solve the problem of the function receiving it as "undefined"? Please help.

backend app.js file -

```
require('./api/data/db.js');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./api/routes');

app.set('port',3000); //Defining port

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.method, req.url);
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // Delivering static files from public folder
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false }));

app.use('/api',routes);

//Setting the port to listen to requests
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  var port = server.address().port; //Extract port number fromserver object
  console.log("App running. Port number - " + port);
});
```

register controller function (node.js backend) -

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res){
console.log("Registering Users");
console.log(req.body.email);
console.log(req.body.fname);
console.log(req.body.lname);
console.log(req.body.password);
var email = req.body.email;
var fname = req.body.fname;
var lname = req.body.lname;
var password = req.body.password;

User.create(
  {
    email: email,
    fname: fname,
    lname: lname,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
  }, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res
        .status(400)
        .json(err);
    } else {
      console.log("User created", user);
      res
        .status(201)
        .json(user);
    }
  }
);
};
```

register controller function (angular.js front-end) -

```
function RegisterController($http){
var vm = this;

vm.register = function(){
var user = {
  email: vm.email,
  fname: vm.fname,
  lname: vm.lname,
  password: vm.password
};

if(!vm.email || !vm.password){
  vm.error = 'Please enter an email and password.';
} else {
  if(vm.password !== vm.passwordRepeat){
    vm.error = 'Please enter matching passwords.';
  } else {
    console.log(user);
    $http.post('/api/users/register', user).then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
      console.log(user);
      vm.message = 'Successful registration! Please login.';
      vm.error= '';
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
}
};
```

Node file with routing -

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var ctrlUsers = require('../controllers/users.controller.js');

router
  .route('/users/register')
  .post(ctrlUsers.register);

module.exports = router;
```

HTML -

```
<h1>Register</h1>

<div ng-if="vm.message" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <p>{{ vm.message }}</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <p>{{ vm.error }}</p>
</div>

<form ng-hide="vm.message" name="register" ng-submit="vm.register()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="vm.email" autocapitalize="none">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" ng-model="vm.password" autocapitalize="none">
  </div>

...some more elements...

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>

</form>
```

console:

```
GET /angular-app/app.js
GET /angular-app/register/register-controller.js
GET /angular-app/register/register.html
POST /api/users/register
Registering Users
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
Error: data and salt arguments required
```

Comment: How do you mount the register function to the route?

Comment: @vizsatiz I realize that it's pretty much the same question, but I didn't find the solution to the password being received as "undefined".

Comment: @JonasW. The angular or the node part?

Comment: The node part ...

Comment: router
  .route('/users/register')
  .post(ctrlUsers.register);

Comment: From your question I can see that user data is not reaching the node server. When is `vm` initialized? If the data is being binded from HTML then you should be initializing with `$scope.vm`. If this does not help can you put in your HTML code

Comment: @vizsatiz Yes, that's exactly my problem. Data is not reaching the server. I've updated the question with the HTML.

Comment: Did you change `var vm` to `$scope.vm` ? ng-model can only update scope variables

Comment: Could you show the whole file were you mount the routes?

Comment: Can you my answer below

Comment: @JonasW. Updating the question with that file.

Comment: And where do you start the server? You are probably missing the body-parser

Comment: @georgeawg In which part are you suggesting I do a console.log(req.body)? In the node file with the register controller function?

Comment: @JonasW. I have the body-parser in the app.js file in the node part. Funny thing is, when I tested the same thing with postman, it worked perfectly. After I built the form is when I started encountering this problem.

Comment: @JonasW. Please see my main app.js file which I've just added to the question. It has the body-parser. Like I said, posting data via postman worked perfectly, once I started getting data from the actual form is when this error popped up.

Comment: Try with `bodyParser.json()` instead of urlencoded.

Comment: @JonasW. IT WORKED! THANK YOU. I can finally sleep now. :)

Comment: @JonasW. Would you mind explaining how you realized that would work and why bodyParser.json() worked and not bodyParser.urlencoded()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your server accepts the posted data in this format:

```
 username=jonas&password=test
```

But the default setting of `$.post` sends it as json:

```
{ "username": "jonas", "password": "test" }
```

To resolve this, either change the data `$.post` sends, or you change the servers bodyparser from `urlencoded` to `json`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

> how [did] you realized that would work?

As you logged the `user` object on the clientside, I assumed that you checked that the data was sent correctly, and your route seemed correct. So the error had to be somewhere on the way between the `$.post` call and the data reaching the route. As you mounted the routes correctly, the only mistake that was left was a missmatch in the encoding of the body.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code. I have not tried running this but hope it gives an idea. Also try using `ng-click` in html

```
function RegisterController($http, $scope){
    $scope.vm = {};

    $scope.register = function() {
       var user = {
      email: $scope.vm.email,
      fname: $scope.vm.fname,
      lname: $scope.vm.lname,
      password: $scope.vm.password
    };

    if(!$scope.vm.email || !$scope.vm.password){
      vm.error = 'Please enter an email and password.';
    } else {
      if($scope.vm.password !== $scope.vm.passwordRepeat){
        $scope.vm.error = 'Please enter matching passwords.';
      } else {
        console.log(user);
        $http.post('/api/users/register', user).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
          console.log(user);
          $scope.vm.message = 'Successful registration! Please login.';
          $scope.vm.error= '';
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }
    }
    };
```

Comment: Got an error in the console -
    angular.js:13642 ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: angular.js:13642 ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at new RegisterController (http://localhost:3000/angular-app/register/register-controller.js:4:3)

Comment: `function RegisterController($http, $scope)` is this how you defined

Comment: My bad, I'd forgotten the $scope in that line. So the error is now not appearing anymore, but nothing is happening after the submit button is pressed. It's almost like no functionality has been added to the button.

Comment: Did you use `ng-click` on the button?

Comment: I used ng-submit="vm.register()" in the form element. If I undo the $scope edit, submit button works but I get back the same 500 Internal Server error and the things mentioned above in the question. :/